# How to have different machines running different task?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system, leader

I have an application in which I have five different tasks. Each of those five tasks runs at different period of time in a particular day. I will be deploying this application in 4 different machines.

In general I was running all those five different tasks on a single machine by choosing the leader between those four machines using Apache Zookeeper. But with this approach other three machines will be sitting idle so I was thinking is there any way I can have different machines running different tasks? Meaning each of those four machines running some tasks from those five but no two machines running the same task.

Can anyone provide an example on how would I do this?

**Update:-**

I don't have any dependency between different tasks. They all are independent of each other.

Comment: Is there a dependency between the different tasks?

Comment: @OferLando No, there is no dependency between different tasks. They are independent of each other.

Comment: Have a look at this project I wrote. It does something similar. You might be able to use it directly or as an example: https://github.com/NirmataOSS/workflow

Answer (score 0):

I would have five nodes: `pending_tasks`, `completed_tasks`, `running_tasks`, `workers`, and `queues`. `pending_tasks` is the node that holds tasks, both new ones and the ones that will be re-triggered due to failures in workers nodes. `completed_tasks` holds completed tasks details. `running_tasks` holds the tasks that are assigned to workers. In a PoC implementation I did once I used XML-encoded POJO to store tasks' details. Nodes in `pending_tasks`, `completed_tasks`, and `running_tasks` are all persistent nodes.

`workers` holds ephemeral nodes that represent available workers. Given they are ephemeral, these nodes signal failures in the workers. `queues` is directly related to `workers`: there is a node in `queues` for each node in `workers`. The nodes in `queues` are used to hold the tasks assigned for each of the workers.

Now, you need a master. The master is responsible for three things: i) watch `pending_tasks` for new tasks; ii) watch `workers` to register new `queues` when new workers arrive, and to put tasks back in `pending_tasks` when workers went missing; and iii) publish the result of the tasks in `completed_tasks` (when I did this PoC, the result would go through a publish/subscribe notification mechanism). Besides that, the master must perform some clean-up in the start-up given that workers might fail during masters' downtime.

The master algorithm is the following:

```
at (start-up) {
  for (q -> /queues) {
    if q.name not in nodesOf(/workers) {
      for (t -> nodesOf(/queues/d.name)) {
        create /pending_tasks/t.name
        delete /running_tasks/t.name
        delete /queues/d.name/t.name
      }
      delete /queues/d.name
    }
  }

  for (t -> nodesOf(/completed_tasks)) {
    publish the result
    deleted /completed_tasks/c.name
  }
}

watch (/workers) {
  case c: Created => register the new worker queue
  case d: Deleted =>  transaction {
    for (t -> nodesOf(/queues/d.name)) {
      create /pending_tasks/t.name
      delete /running_tasks/t.name
      delete /queues/d.name/t.name
    }
    delete /queues/d.name
  }
}

watch (/pending_tasks) {
  case c: Created => transaction {
    create /running_tasks/c.name
    create persistent node in one of the workers queue (eg, /queues/worker_0/c.name)
    delete /pending_tasks/c.name
  }
}

watch (/completed_tasks) {
  case c: Created =>
    publish the result
    deleted /completed_tasks/c.name
}
```

The worker algorithm is the following:

```
at (start-up) {
  create /queue/this.name
  create a ephemeral node /workers/this.name
}

watch (/queue/this.name) {
  case c: Created =>
    perform the task
    transaction {
      create /completed_tasks/c.name with the result
      delete /queues/this.name/c.name
      delete /running_tasks/c.name
    }
}
```

Some notes on when I thought of this design. First, at any given time, no tasks targeting the same computation were to run. Therefore, I named the tasks after the computation that was in place. So, if two different clients requested the same computation, only one would succeed since only one would be able to create the `/pending_tasks` node. Likewise, if the task is already running, the creation of the `/running_task/` node would fail and no new task would be dispatch.

Second, there might be arbitrary failures in both masters and workers and no task will be lost. If a worker fails, the watching of delete events in `/worker` will trigger the reassignment of tasks. If a master fail and any given number of workers fail before a new master is in place, the start-up procedure will move tasks back to `/pending_tasks` and publish any pending result.

Third, I might have forgotten some corner case since I have no access to this PoC implementation anymore. I'll be glad to discuss any issue.